# How to make an automatic value calculator in Excel?

Tags: excel

I tried the conversion formula:

```
=CONVERT(A1,"m","yd")
```

but all I got was unit change.

I want to convert an entire row's cells values with the change of one cell.
I want to put all the nutritional information values in a row per 100 grams in a cell but when I change for let's say 150 grams instead of 100 grams, I want it to automatically calculate and convert the entire row's values as if it were 150.
How can I do that?

Comment: If you have 100 in A1, then all the other cells should contain A1 or $A1, so when you change 100 to 150, depending on the formulas, all the values (not necessarily) would automatically change (increase or decrease) 1.5 times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a sheet with all the values, all based on your standard, for example, 100 grams. Let's call this sheet "Sheet1".
2. In Sheet1!A1 write the base value, like `100` if the base is 100 grams.
3. Create a second, identical sheet. Let's call this one "Sheet2". This sheet has the same formatting as Sheet1 but no values. The only exception is Sheet2!A1 to which you assign the value of `100` (a number, not text).
4. Write this formula in Sheet2!A2: `=Sheet1!A2 / Sheet1!$A$1 * $A$1`. Copy the formula down and across all used cells.

At this point Sheet2 looks exactly like Sheet1. However, if you change the value in Sheet2!A1 to, say 150, all values will be increased by 50%.